# Math.Pow vs scientific notation

Tags: c#, pow, scientific-notation

I would like to know if there is difference between writing `Math.Pow(10, -3)` and `1E-3`. When I `Console.WriteLine` both values I get the same output, so is there a reason to prefer one over another?

Comment: One performs a mathematical operation, the other one is a compile time value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call [`Math.Pow(10, -3)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netcore-3.1) then .NET will calculate the value each time and calculation will affect your performance because this method works for double-precision floating-point number as power.

`1E-3` is just a number so there is no need to calculate it in runtime.

It's better and more clearly to use [numeric literals](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpNumericLiterals.aspx) instead of multiply operator and it's better to use multiply operator instead of `Math.Pow` when it's possible.

[Here is a benchmark](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jIwbZc) that shows that numeric literal requires almost zero time to execute.

Comment: Use BenchmarkDotNet for benchmarks. This is so cheap that it's going to be hard to get accurate numbers (how do you even measure the cost of declaring a literal, anyway? That's as near to free as you can get. What you're measuring there is the loop overhead and delegate invocation cost)